# Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument' what(): stof. Input is from a .txt file

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to put information from a .txt file into a linked list. Since some of them are values of money such as grosspay and netpay, I have to convert them from string to float. However my program won't run since it encounters the error std::invalid argument and won't accept the values and convert them.

```
    //Variable Declarations
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream myfile("C:\\Users\\marbe\\Desktop\\FINALS 1ST YEAR S.Y. 2019 - 2020\\PayrollRecords.txt");


    //while file is open, traverse by line
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        int count = 0;
        while ( std::getline (myfile,line) )
        {
        //count determines which line getfile is at the current node
        switch(count)
        {
            case 0:
                pnode.emp_num = line;
            break;

            case 1:
                pnode.rateperd = stof(line);
            break;

            case 2:
                pnode.rateperh = stof(line);
            break;
            
            case 3:
                pnode.otrate = stof(line);
            break;
            
            case 4:
                pnode.pr_date = line;
            break;

            case 5:
                pnode.grosspay = stof(line);
            break;

            case 6:
                pnode.socialsecurity = stof(line);
            break;

            case 7:
                pnode.homefund = stof(line);
            break;

            case 8:
                pnode.incometax = stof(line);
            break;

            case 9:
                pnode.totaldeductions = stof(line);
            break;

            case 10:
                pnode.netpay = stof(line);
            break;
        }

        //if within the bounds of the node, continue adding
        if(count < 11)
        {
            count++;
        }

        //once reached the end of the node, reset count to 0 and push node into list
        else
        {
            count = 0;
            PayrollRecords.push_back(pnode);
            payempcount++;
        }

        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    else std::cout << "Unable to open file" << std::endl;
```

Here is an example of what the .txt file contains

E001
1000.00
125.00
500.00
01/30/2021
32250.00
4837.50
645.00
6450.00
11932.50
20317.50

E002
1500.00
187.50
500.00
02/28/2021
47250.00
7087.50
945.00
9450.00
17482.50
29767.50

Comment: Is there a blank line in your file between records? You don't seem to handle that. It'll all be off by one on the second record and `E002` isn't a float.

Comment: What string is being passed to `stof` when it throws the exception? You could boil the program down to just an `stof` call with that string, but there's a very good chance you'll have solved the problem by then.

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes there is one line in between records so let's say I have E001 - E010 I have 9 lines in between records for the last record let's say in this case E010, I have 2 blank lines the 2nd to the last blank line then the last blank line.

Comment: I would add `if (line.empty()) { continue; }` before the `switch`.

Comment: Besides checking the empty string, we still need to catch exceptions here to handle ill-format input lines.

Comment: @chris I did what you said and you were right one of the records lacked one line of info and it threw off the rest of the .txt file. It now works thank you!